# SQLITE_NOMEM error on Linux 64 bits

Tags: linux, sqlite, 64-bit, labview

I am trying to use Sqlite3 on linux 64 bits with LabVIEW.

I have successfully compiled the library for linux 64 bits (RHEL6) with different versions of SQLITE sources.

Then I tried to call that library with 2 existing SQLITE wrappers for LabVIEW (They already work fine respectively for win32/64 and for win32/linux32), using a simple example.

This simple example does the following (and works fine on win32/win64/linux32) :

- `Open connection`
- `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`
- `CREATE TABLE [MyTable] ([Id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [Temperature] FLOAT NOT NULL, [Sensor] TEXT NULL);`
- `INSERT INTO MyTable (Sensor, Temperature) VALUES ("%s", "%0.2f");`
- ...

With **version 3.8.7 (lastest)** of sqlite3 :
I get a crash of LabVIEW when calling the sqlite3_step with the `CREATE TABLE` statement

With **version 3.7.5** of sqlite3 :
I get a `SQLITE_NOMEM` out of memory error on the same function call

I get the same beaviour with the 2 LabVIEW wrappers and checked them, so I don't suspect the LabVIEW code

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What wrappers are these?

Comment: SQLite Library for LabVIEW by Dr. James Powell and GDataBase for SQLite - SAPHIR

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the authors of the wrappers how they compiled SQLite (i.e. which defines they used). I can assure you that it's very very unlikely this has to do with SQLite itself.

One possibility that comes to my is that your program makes use of db meta data but wasn't defined at compile time (define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA).

See also here: http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html

Comment: Just one remark : I realized that there was an embedded version of  SQLite (v3.6.2) on my distib of Linux.
I did the simple test with this library, and I also get a crash of LabVIEW...

So the results are the following :

version 3.8.7, with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1,  SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3, SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE compile options (default options with amalgation source code): crash
version 3.7.5, same compile options as above: SQLITE_NOMEM out of memory error
version 3.6.2, unknown compile options (certainly default) : crash

Also did the test with SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA option but no improvement.